# onclick срабатывает со второго клика, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, css

onclick работает не корректно, срабатывает со второго клика, предполагаю что это из-за вложенности блоков, но не знаю как это исправить на деле

HTML:

```
<div class="geo_container">
      <img src="./assets/geo.png" class="geo">
        <select name="select" class="spb" onclick="arrowMenu()">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
        <img src="./assets/Rectangle50.png" class="rectangle">
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function arrowMenu() {
  const select = document.querySelector('.spb')
  const arrowValue = document.querySelector('.rectangle')
  select.addEventListener('click', arrow)
  function arrow() {
    arrowValue.style.transform = arrowValue.style.transform == "rotate(-180deg)" ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(-180deg)"
    arrowValue.classList.add('transition_arrow')
  }
}
```

Comment: а зачем тут вообще `select.addEventListener` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, реагирует на клик когда открывается select, переворачивает стрелку, а как по-другому ?

Comment: а зачем тогда `onclick="arrowMenu()"` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если функцию в онклике не передавать, то скрипт не работает, почему я не знаю

Comment: ну вот тебе надо обработать событие клика на селект.... ты повесил эту обработку непосредственно в html, вопрос: зачем **это же событие** нужно внутри функции обработки этого события?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так по сути функция уже должна работать на addEventListener, без onclick, но она не работает, я просто не вижу в ней ошибки, что не так ? Скрипт подключен, все ок вроде

Comment: ну чтобы что-то работало на `addEventListener` видимо надо помещать `addEventListener` не внутрь функции? логично?))  ну или как минимум вызвать эту функцию сразу же для исполнения

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, точно, просто вызвал обе функции и всё)))))Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно удалить лишнюю функцию `arrrow`. Ваш обработчик срабатывает со второго раза, потому что функция `arrowMenu` вместо выполнения нужного действия лишь привязывает к нажатию ещё один обработчик `arrow`. Который при 2м нажатии и срабатывает. Удалите функцию `arrow`, а ее код вставьте напрямую в `arrowMenu`:

```
function arrowMenu() {
  const select = document.querySelector('.spb')
  const arrowValue = document.querySelector('.rectangle')
  
  arrowValue.style.transform = arrowValue.style.transform == "rotate(-180deg)" ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(-180deg)"
  arrowValue.classList.add('transition_arrow')
  
}
```